# onchange in designed select doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this little problem and I am asking if maybe can somebody help me.

I have a disegned select with a icon for each option. This very cool working, but if I try to make or to call the onchange method for this select is just not working. Is like if this method doesn't exist! If I remove the desing, then everything is very find and again the select (without desing) and the onchange method are friends.

Here is my code in the case that somebody needs
This is the select:

```
<select id="select" class="form-control">
            <option value="de" data-class="deu" id="de" selected>1</option>
            <option value="en" data-class="eng" id="en">2</option>                     
</select>
```

With this code I give the design to the select

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $.widget( "custom.iconselectmenu", $.ui.selectmenu, {
      _renderItem: function( ul, item ) {
        var li = $( "<li>", { text: item.label } );

        if ( item.disabled ) {
          li.addClass( "ui-state-disabled" );
        }

        $( "<span>", {
          style: item.element.attr( "data-style" ),
          "class": "ui-icon " + item.element.attr( "data-class" )
        })
          .appendTo( li );

        return li.appendTo( ul );
      }
    });

    $( "#select" )
      .iconselectmenu()
      .iconselectmenu( "menuWidget" )
        .addClass( "ui-menu-icons customicons" );


  });
</script>

<style>

    .ui-icon.deu {
      background: url("/img/de.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
    }
    .ui-icon.eng {
      background: url("/img/gb.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
    }

</style>
```

and this is my onchange

```
$(select).change(function(){
        alert("Schön!");
    });
```

Comment: why don't you just call that function inside your `<select>` tag? You can just `<select onchange="alert(Schön!');">` it

Comment: Are you getting any error in console? Which all js have you added reference to (is it jqueryUI widget which you are using?)

Comment: @Taleeb yes I am using also boostrap and I am not getting any error in the console

Comment: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/kvm8bznp/). Do let me know if this  does not work for you

Answer (score 0):

You forget to type '#' and also type it in string format.

```
$("#select").change(function(){
    alert("Schön!");
});
```

Comment: Hi Hendry! I just declare a alias for #select like this: var select = $("#select") for that reason I called $(select) and not $("#select")

Answer (score 0):

For select, "change" does not work in this way. Add this

```
  $("#select").change(callFunction);//call function
  //define it
  function callFunction(){
   alert("Schön!");
 }
```

Comment: Hi Abhishek! I tried your way but is still not working :(

Comment: Make sure JQuery is loading before this script and put the first line of code in `$(document).ready(function(){  //code here });` block. After that, declare function out of this block but in the same script tag.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the trigger `change` to `selectmenuchange`

```
$("#select").on('selectmenuchange',function(){
    alert("Schön!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When using jqueryUI widget - I think (not 100% sure) - change event needs to be added with selectmenu event.

```
$.widget("custom.iconselectmenu", $.ui.selectmenu, {
    _renderItem: function (ul, item) {
        var li = $("<li>", {
            text: item.label
        });

        if (item.disabled) {
            li.addClass("ui-state-disabled");
        }

        $("<span>", {
            style: item.element.attr("data-style"),
                "class": "ui-icon " + item.element.attr("data-class")
        })
            .appendTo(li);

        return li.appendTo(ul);
    }

});

$("#select")
    .iconselectmenu({
    change: function (event, ui) {
        console.log('here')
    }
})
    .iconselectmenu("menuWidget")
    .addClass("ui-menu-icons customicons");
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/kvm8bznp/)